# AngularJS : отсортировать выводимые данные по дате, с кнопкой для возможности выбора направления сортировки ( по возрастанию или убыванию )?

Tags: angularjs

Подскажите плиз, как с помощью AngularJS отсортировать выводимые данные по дате, с кнопкой для возможности выбора направления сортировки ( по возрастанию или убыванию ) ?

Если только одну конкретную сортировку задать, то вот так работает:

```
// JS
$scope.myDateFunction = function(date) {
        return new Date(date)
};
// HTML
<tr ng-repeat="cd in cds | orderBy: myDateFunction">
<!-- <tr ng-repeat="cd in cds | orderBy: -myDateFunction"> -->
```

Если добавить перед myDateFunction знак - , то сортирует и в обратном порядке.

Проблема в том, как сделать чтобы была возможность выбирать направление сортировки по нажатию кнопки.

Пробовал создать объект для получения знака минус в $scope.

```
// JS
$scope.selectedSoleDate = function() {
        if($scope.selectedChoiseDate.name=="asc") {$scope.selectedDateChoise=''}
        if($scope.selectedChoiseDate.name=="desc") {$scope.selectedDateChoise='-'}
};
```

Но тогда непонятно как этот минус подставить в фильтр orderBy. 
Типа этого не работает:

```
<tr ng-repeat="cd in cds | orderBy: selectedDateChoise + myDateFunction">
```

Как решить проблему, в каком направлении смотреть?

Answer (score 2):

Фильтры [`orderBy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) принимает несколько параметров, один из которых

- reverse - если `true`, изменить порядок сортировки.

Поэтому достаточно передавать в этот параметр `true` или `false` в зависимости от направления

В разметке это будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
<tr ng-repeat="cd in cds | orderBy: myDateFunction:reverse">
```

Где `reverse` - это переменная хранящая `true` или `false`

Возможно так же использовать непосредственно переменные `$scope.selectedChoiseDate.name` например так:

```
<tr ng-repeat="cd in cds | orderBy: myDateFunction:selectedChoiseDate.name=='desc'">
```

Comment: Работает. Спасибо Grundy